# Visa when having a Canadian partner (out of marriage)?

Tags: canada, working-visas, immigration

It is common to see married people benefiting from dual citizenship.

But what about being partner with a Canadian citizen, but without being married? Would it ease the procedures to obtain a work permit? Permanent residence? and what marital status is valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be able to obtain a Canadian permanent residency a Canadian citizen can sponsor you for permanent residency.  To determine eligibility you can look at the [CIC page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/sponsor/spouse-apply-who.asp), which states:

> You can apply to sponsor your spouse, common-law or conjugal partner, or dependent children to immigrate to Canada. It does not matter if they live in or outside Canada. If they live in Canada, they do not need to have legal status to be sponsored.

The question becomes whether or not you will qualify as a common-law or conjugal partner.  For that you can look at help center for definitions:

- [Common-Law partner](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=346&t=14):

  > You may apply to sponsor a common-law partner, of the opposite sex or the same sex. If so, you have to prove you have been living with your partner for at least **12 consecutive months** in a relationship like a marriage.
- [Conjugal Partner](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/glossary.asp#conjugal_partner):

  > A person outside Canada who has had a binding relationship with a sponsor for at least one year but could not live with their partner. The term refers to both opposite-sex and same-sex relationships.

So if you can prove these should be able to get a sponsorship for Canadian Permanent Residency.